# Really struggling to format sticky menu (CSS)

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am so nearly there with this site. I have the got the front page looking exactly as I want - the nav menu sits just right in the white bar, etc. Problem is when you go to any other page (page section) and the nav slides up to the top.

The bar is then too big (height) and I cannot find the write bit of CSS to change it! There are quite a few classes that have a "min-height" attribute and I have fiddled with these but to no avail.

Any chance one of you fine people can have a quick look?

http://growing-underground.com/ (password = nugget13)

Thank you.

Comment: `.is-sticky { height: DesiredHeight !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find the height of the navigation bar. The class called ".is-sticky" is setting the height to 90px, so you could change that accordingly or just not apply that class to the navigation bar which will match the min-height that is currently set on it from the class element.style.

I'll have a look at the rest after lunch :)

Comment: No problem. It's a very nice site design by the way and what is it about - eating natural and healthy foods?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by jumpingcode  change `.issticky` height: xx; and also change, this piece of code to re-align secions properly.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+parentSection).offset().top -80 }, 1000);
```

change `80` to `xx-10` where `xx` is the height of `.issticky`

or you can simply add this script

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+parentSection).offset().top -($(".issticky").height() -10)}, 1000);
```